# HTTP Request Mapping to Different Channels - Spring MVC Framework

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-integration

I have a requirement, where i need to process HTTP Request in below manner

1) HTTP Request with `channelId`.

1a) Each `channel id` will uniquely identify `one channel`.

1b) There can be multiple channels running with different ChannelIds in parallel

1c) New channel will be created at runtime for each new unique ChannelId

2) Each HTTP Request at server end will set the `TIME` for that channel and activates a thread

3) If time difference between `{Last Set Time}` and now is `less than 10 sec`, there is continous thread running, which will be calling webservice and fetching data after every 2 seconds.

4) In case time exceeds 10 seconds, thread stops.

I have Java Spring MVC application, in which i need to do this, I have tried reading on Spring Integration for this purpose, but not able to find how to use it for this scenarios.

In case of any doubts in question, please leave your comments, i'll explain it.
Any pointers in this direction will be helpful and appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you need new channels for each request. The incoming HTTP request is bounded to some container Thread and if you will use just **direct channel** you'll get the same result.
If your subscriber to that channel is thread-safe everything will be OK. Method invocation concept.
Or provide, please, more info regarding your item 2).